# Show that for $(A,*)$ algebraic system $a*(a*b) = a*b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, magma

Suppose we are given that for algebraic system $(A,*)$ that
$$(a*b)*a = a $$ and $$(a*b)*b = (b*a)*a$$ then how can I show that   $$a*(a*b) = a*b$$ 
such that $a,b$ belongs to $A$?

---

I know that $(a*b)$ is left identity from first relation but what conclusion I can draw from second given relation to show required relation? 
I tried to reach to any of two given relation from required relation by

$$a*(a*b)*a = (a*b)*a$$
$$a*a = a$$

Now what? this could have been proved if $a$ were identity but that does not seem to be case here.

Comment: Use what you have proved and observe $a\ast (a\ast b) = (a\ast a) \ast b = a\ast b$? I'm assuming $\ast$ is associative.

Comment: @JackyChong Whether this is associative or not is unknown.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ constants, or arbitrary elements of $A$? And in the latter case, are the formulas also valid for $a=b$?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way you can prove it, because it is false. Take the semigroup with zero $S = \{a, b, ab, ba, 0\}$ defined by the relations $aba = a$, $bab = b$, $aa = 0$ and $bb = 0$. Then $(ab)a = a$, $(ab)b = (ba)a = 0$, but $a(ab) = 0 \not=  ab$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

a*(a*b)=[(a*b)*a]*(a*b)=a*b

Notice that we only need to use the first identity twice.The rest of other two are useless!